# Prevent Ubuntu from breaking wifi connection on lid close

Tags: power-management

I have my power settings on Ubuntu to suspend when inactive for 10 minutes. And I have set my 'Power on lid close on battery' as Do Nothing. However, with this setting my laptop doesn't suspend itself if I close my lid but neither does it suspend itself and by the time I get home the laptop is completely dead. If I set my 'Power on lid close on battery' to Suspend then it suspends itself however, it also cuts out all the wifi and VPN connections. Is there a way I set my laptop such on lid close it does nothing and preserve the wifi and VPN connections but after 10 minutes of inactivity whether lid closed or not suspends itself?

Comment: That question that this is supposed to be a dupe of is from ubuntu 10.10 and is so outdated that is does not apply. Not to mention the fact that none of the answers would even work.

Comment: @mchid so why reopen this? Why not post an updated answer to that post?

Comment: That's impossible. Either you shut down or suspend the computer off or you leave it running. You can't leave it running partially because a partially active system is still an active system that requires power.

Comment: @muru Aside from the outdated stuff, it looks like this question is asking about how to make the laptop suspend after and not before 10 minutes of inactivity whether the laptop lid is closed or open. It looks like the OP here has a laptop that does suspend after 10 minutes of inactivity when the lid is open but does not suspend after 10 minutes of inactivity when the lid is closed.